# Popup display in table scrolled

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, popup

I asked previously an incomplete question...
I repost with a JSFiddle reproducing my problem:

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/q57zv7oo/6/)

This example is working in Mozilla but not working in IE or Chrome.

Explanation:
I a table who represent a static header. A second containing rows.
Eache rows have 2 table cell.
The first cell can be mouseHover to show a popup on his position.
The problem is that the popup it's not correctly display in space when i have the table scrolled on chrome and IE but in Mozilla it does.

Cell with popup show on hover:

```
<div id="divCellule" runat="server" onmouseover="javascript:$(this).find("#infobulle").show();" onmouseout="javascript:$(this).find("#infobulle").hide();">
    <div class="infobulle" id="infobulle">
        <span>Title</title>
    </div>
    <span>063</span>
</div>
```

Each cell are in a row of table. The table is in a div "overflow"

Code:

```
<div class="overflow">
  <table class="table_planning">
      <tr>
         <td>
             <-CELL->
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
             <-CELL->
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
             <-CELL->
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
             <-CELL->
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
             <-CELL->
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.overflow {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    max-height: 450px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

CSS of table is in the Fiddle (too long).

Hope it's explain better...

Answer (score 1):

Plz Add Top & Left position

```
.table_planning .infobulle{left:20px; top;50px}
```

Comment: Hello and thank's for reply. It's working on the JSFiddle but it's positionning top and left on page position and not on the div position.
In my example there is no Menu and Header of Page ;)
Sorry for this miss. If you add some <br> before the two table your solution is not working anymore... I'm sad for this...

Comment: I've resolve the issue! Thank's for help ;) You take me on the way

Answer (score 1):

[The OP wrote in an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que):

> I've resolve the issue! On each div containing the popup I've got two events:

```
onMouseHover='ShowInfoBulle(this);'
onMouseOut='HideInfoBulle(this);'

function ShowInfoBulle(sender) {
            var cell = $(sender);
            var infobulle = cell.find('#infobulle');
            var cellOffsetLeft = cell.offset().left;
            var cellOffsetTop = cell.offset().top;
            infobulle.css("top", cellOffsetTop + "px");
            infobulle.css("left", cellOffsetLeft + "px");
            infobulle.show();
        }

function HideInfoBulle(sender) {
            $(sender).find('#infobulle').hide();
        }
```